# Validate a subset of or only certain elements of an XML document?

Tags: xml, perl, validation, xsd

I have this XML file (some of them are HUGE - thousands of elements) and I'm trying to validate certain elements of this XML file using an XSD schema. For eg. dates, etc. Now, the problem is that XSD won't let me validate just certain sections of the document. It wants definitions for EVERYTHING - and that would be quite painful. What I would like to know is that is there a way to XSD work with only certain elements of the document? I've tried any and anyAttribute to no avail. If not, how would you do this? Is there a library/script that produces a schema corresponding to an XML document which I can then modify according to my needs?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean that XSD wants definitions for everything? How do yo know that? What "XSD" are you talking about? What does it mean for "XSD" to "want definitions"?

Comment: You might want to show the code you use to validate. How to accomplish this task probably depends on the tools you're using - it usually does.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have a schema file and I'm trying to validate an XML document against that schema. The schema file has restrictions and type settings for only certain elements that I want to validate. When I validate against this schema file using XML::LibXML::Schema, I get errors about the other elements not defined in the file. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have also `<xs:element name="aName"/>` wich match the ur-type, so any type.

A typical partial validation would be :

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:element name="theRootElement">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <!- some wildcard wich match the beginning of the document until the desired element -->
    <xs:any processContent="skip" namespace="somethingOrAll"/>

    <xs:element name="theDesiredElementToMatch">
     <!-- the matching test -->
    </xs:element>

    <!-- the rest of the doc -->
    <xs:any processContent="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But it's doesn't work with all schemas, and it's very tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the pieces you care about to document fragment DOMs and run validation against those. Assuming, of course, that you are programming some language with an API to all of this.

Comment: I'm using Perl, so I'm sure it can be done. However, I'm dealing with a lot of different types of documents (User, Order, etc.) and having a different subroutine for each different type of document to validate only certain parts seems unnecessary (maintenance hell!). It would be awesome to just include those fields in the schema and then keep adding more fields to the schema when we need to validate more fields.

Comment: It might be awesome, but it's not a feature of XML Schema You could try relaxng or some such.

Comment: Yup, for the moment, a lot of `processContent="skip"` and `<xs:any>` and `<xs:anyAttributes>` seems to be doing the job. However, I'd be open to better alternatives.